# Disable ubuntu kernel update utility

Tags: kernel, updates

I am getting real sick of this popup window which has to pop up every single effing day.

[image]

It moves focus from whatever I am working on. If I cancel it, it will popup again in a few hours. If I install the update, there will be new one the next day.

Perhaps, I do not want to disable it altogether. It would be nice for a notification every month or so.

Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: @guiverc This must be a UKUU message.

Comment: You installed UKUU and run mainline kernels. That is generally not the best idea. If you know what you are doing, then there must be some settings in UKUU that disable these notifications.

Comment: Ahan. I assumed this was part of the OS. I have no recollection of explicitly installing ukuu. Is it ok to remove this then?

Comment: This is NOT a part of the system. It isn't even available in Ubuntu repositories. You will need to uninstall it and uninstall mainline kernels to switch back to supported ones.

Comment: Oh Ok. Thanks for this info.

Comment: See https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of completeness. Turns out it's called ukuu.

[image]

And under Settings, there is an option to change notification frequency.

[image]